# Symmetries of circle

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone please help me understand the symmetries of G, where G is the group of the symmetries of the circle. Prove that G has elements of order n for all positive n integers, as as elements of infinitive order.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider rotations with angle $2\pi t$ for rational and irrational $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Rotation by 2$\pi$/n degrees has order n.